Truffle deploying Error: PollingBlockTracker
I have attempted to deploy the contracts through Polygon Amoy and Sepolia, and both of them produce the same error. I have launched Ganache with the same MNEMONIC as the MetaMask wallet and the one used in .secret file.
The network used in MetaMask is also the same as the one used in the truffle-config.js

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
⠇ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/payment-dapp/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/payment-dapp/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

truffle-config.js
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const fs = require("fs");
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    sepolia: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          mnemonic,
          `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/`
        ),
      network_id: 11155111,
      confirmations: 2,
      gas: 5500000,
      gasPrice: 45000000,
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
      chainId: 11155111,
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: "./contracts",
  contracts_build_directory: "./abis",
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.19",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },

  db: {
    enabled: false,
  },
};


PollingBlockTracker error occurs when your configuration is not correct. I think most likely the error is here https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/. from infura network endpoints you should be adding the API KEY
https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<API-KEY>

Also, you may need to change the host to this
  host: "127.0.0.1",

instead of "localhost"

I still get the error : Error: Unhandled error. ({Seconds: 10   code: -32603,   message: 'Too Many Requests',

On another app with similar configuration, I get Error: Unhandled error. ({   code: -32603,   message: 'ETIMEDOUT',   data: { originalError: { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true } }

Free Infura accounts now only allow for "one" active API key at a time. if you have previously created, delete them.
